# Can we compute the entropy of a subsystem of a quantum state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, density-operator

Suppose there is some entangled system with 5 subsystems labeled 1 to 5. Can we write the density operator for the subspace of subsystems 1 to 4 and compute entropy and the other relations with it completely ignoring subsystem 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question you asked in your paragraph is yes, as explained below.

First, here's an example using a system of five particles. Let $\psi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ be the wavefunction of the five-particle system. To ignore the 5th particle, use the density operator
$$
  \rho(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4|x_1',x_2',x_3',x_4')
 = \int dx_5\ \psi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\psi^*(x'_1,x'_2,x'_3,x'_4,x_5).
$$
This is a "matrix" in which each of the two "indices" is a 4-tuple of real numbers, $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ and $(x_1',x_2',x_3',x_4')$.

More generally, suppose the Hilbert space is 
$$
H=H_1\otimes H_2\otimes H_3\otimes H_4\otimes H_5.
$$
We can write this as $H=H_{1234}\otimes H_5$ with
$$
H_{1234}=H_1\otimes H_2\otimes H_3\otimes H_4.
$$
In other words, we can treat the first four subsystems as a single subsystem, and then calculate the density matrix (and von Neumann entanglement entropy, etc) as we usually do for a bipartite system. Explicitly, if the state-vector of the 5-part system is
$$
  |\psi\rangle = \sum_{i,j,k,\ell,m}c_{ijk\ell m}|i\rangle\otimes |j\rangle\otimes |k\rangle\otimes |\ell\rangle\otimes |m\rangle
= \sum_{i,j,k,\ell,m}c_{ijk\ell m}|ijk\ell\rangle\otimes |m\rangle
$$
(using an orthogonal basis for each subsystem),
then the density operator obtained by ignoring the 5th subsystem is
$$
  \rho=\sum_m c_{ijk\ell m}c^*_{i'j'k'\ell'm}
  \big(|ijk\ell\rangle\, \langle i'j'k'\ell'|\big)\langle m|m\rangle.
$$